# Difference in Expression.Subtract for DateTime between .NET Core and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, expression-trees, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

While converting my `.NET 4.5` library to `.NETStandard v1.6` I ran into a failing unit test which used to pass before.

I pinpointed the problem to the following three lines of code:

```
ParameterExpression arg1 = Expression.Parameter( typeof( DateTime ), "arg1" );
ParameterExpression arg2 = Expression.Parameter( typeof( DateTime ), "arg2" );
var test = Expression.Subtract( arg1, arg2 );
```

This expression tree compiles for `.NET 4.5`, but throws an `InvalidOperationException` in `.NETStandard v1.6`:

> The binary operator Subtract is not defined for the types
>   'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'.

However, for both targets the following code works:

```
DateTime one = new DateTime();
DateTime two = new DateTime();
TimeSpan difference = one - two;
```

I thus would expect the expression trees to compile for .NET Core as well? Am I doing something wrong, or [is this a bug in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11907)?

Comment: I just tried with constant expressions (`Expression.Constant( DateTime.Now )`) for which the same occurs.

Comment: From [a quick glance at the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.0.0-rc2/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/BinaryExpression.cs#L758), `GetUserDefinedBinaryOperator` seems to be returning `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in `System.Linq.Expressions` assembly.

These methods are used to find the Subtract operator method:

```
public static MethodInfo GetAnyStaticMethodValidated(this Type type, string name, Type[] types)
{
    // Method name is "op_Subtraction" in your case
    MethodInfo anyStaticMethod = type.GetAnyStaticMethod(name);
    // DateTime and DateTime in your case
    if (!anyStaticMethod.MatchesArgumentTypes(types))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return anyStaticMethod;
}

public static MethodInfo GetAnyStaticMethod(this Type type, string name)
{
    foreach (MethodInfo current in type.GetRuntimeMethods())
    {
        if (current.IsStatic && current.Name == name)
        {
            return current;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you see, the `GetAnyStaticMethod` picks randomly the first "op_Subtraction" method from `DateTime`, instead of looping through all available, where `DateTime` has two of such operator methods:

```
public static DateTime operator -(DateTime d, TimeSpan t);
public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime d1, DateTime d2);
```

So the code picks the wrong one that takes in `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`, then just fails because input types don't match.

In .NET 4.5 they do search in a proper way by passing argument types:

```
Type[] types = new Type[]
{
    leftType, // DateTime in your case
    rightType // DateTime in your case
};
BindingFlags bindingAttr = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
// Method name is "op_Subtraction" in your case
MethodInfo methodInfo = nonNullableType.GetMethodValidated(name, bindingAttr, null, types, null);
```

Comment: Awesome. to you the honor of [reporting the exact issue on the github project](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11907). :) I will update the issue to point out you found the exact reason behind it.

Comment: I might consider it later if nobody that has actual experience with this jumps on it instantly. First I want to continue migrating my library (including finding a workaround for this). :)

Comment: The work around is quite simple: find the right operator method by yourself and pass as the third arg to the overloaded `Expression.Subtract` method

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a bug in the implementation of .NET Core. The reason is that certain APIs were not avaiable in .NET Core when System.Linq.Expressions was ported to core, so a custom implementation was developed and this was never caught.

I've [sent a PR to dotnet/corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/11920) to fix this.
For the curious, the problem was that the method finding the operator loops through the methods, but breaks out of the loop when it finds a match, before checking that the method is the one we want. The fix is to move parameter checking inside the loop, e.g.

```
        internal static MethodInfo GetAnyStaticMethodValidated(
        this Type type,
        string name,
        Type[] types)
    {
        foreach (var method in type.GetRuntimeMethods())
        {
            if (method.IsStatic && method.Name == name && method.MatchesArgumentTypes(types))
            {
                return method;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Not too certain since I can't see the full codebase here, but does this also verify the return type? Or, I suppose since you can't overload on return type there is no need to check for this. :) Just want to double check the pull request covers all angles. Might also be interesting to add some unit tests for this since this went uncaught before.

Comment: Oh, I see you did add a unit test. So this code should probably also cover DateTime - TimeSpan, ... correct?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I added another unit test